# Use python function from C++

Tags: python, c++, minimization

I have following code in python:

```
from scipy import optimize
def f(x):
  return .5*(1 - x[0])**2 + (x[1] - x[0]**2)**2
print optimize.fmin_cg(f, [2, 2])
```

Is there any way to call `optimize.fmin_cg()` from C++ (or C).

I need to use above function from my `C++` code.

Answer (score 2):

Check boost.python library. [Calling Python Functions and Methods](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/python/doc/v2/callbacks.html)